# Google Maps and Displaying Coordinates while drawing?

Tags: google-maps, mouse-position

Currently we are doing this on a project:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function (event) {
    displayCoordinates(event.latLng);               
});

function displayCoordinates(pnt) {
    var coordsLabel = document.getElementById("tdCursor");
    var lat = pnt.lat();
    lat = lat.toFixed(4);
    var lng = pnt.lng();
    lng = lng.toFixed(4);
    coordsLabel.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + lat + "  Longitude: " + lng;
}
```

However, when we go to draw a polygon this no longer works.  We had to attach another event to the polygon mouseover once it is drawn to call displayCoordinates, but we are having a hard time finding what to call how to implement this with Google Maps.  ESRI and OpenLayers makes this kind of stuff easier IME.